# (tortoise) svn: relocate different branches to different repositories (= different URL and UUID)

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm working on a project for let's say two different companies A and B; A is a big one and B a small one (mine). Both companies work on the same project, but mine is only working on a small module of the big one. So we have one repository for the hole project of A and another one only for the few files that B is working on.

What I want is to check out the main project from A's repository (branch main), develop on a small subset of files (branch develop) and commit them to B's repository. But now I'm facing the following problem: I want to seperate the two branches to different repository locations / repositories with different URLs and UUIDs. (How) can I manage that?

(If this won't work with svn / tortoise-svn, will git-svn instead do the trick?)

Answer (score 1):

Vendor Branch and svn:externals

"branch main" of repo A added as "some-branch" in repo B tree. "branch develop" developed inside clean repo B tree, finished branch linked with svn:exnernals again from repo A

Comment: Vendor branches are indeed the solution (that I wasn't aware of), but these two lines of explanation poorly convey the message. Please explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Branching and merging in SVN only work on the same repository. So there is no way to reach what you want to get.

However, if you would state what you want to reach, perhaps there could be a solution:

- Decouple the development for company A and B, so that there is no overlap?
- Work on your small project (without that will ever be noticed at the big project), but share the files?
- ...

If the second one is interesting, the following could work:

1. Checkout the big project locally with SVN.
2. Create there a new Git repository.
3. Clone that Git repository locally to a separate location.
4. Work on that separate repository, and push your changes when you think you should deliver them to the big project.
5. Commit then the changes in your Subversion working copy (which is at the same time your working copy of the Git repository) to the big project.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have two working copies A and B and copy files manually from A to B.

If company A would allow it you can branch a project within repository A and import that branch as external repository to your project B. The downside is that company A will have your source code in its repository.

EDIT: One repository may include folders from another repository through [`svn:external`](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html) property. You basically declare in your repository that some folder will actually be complete working copy of some other repository. In your case that "some other repository" is actually a branch of the project that you are interested in. When you add a property (with folder name and URL of a branch in another repository) just update the working copy and Tortoise will download all the files from another repository. A little downside is that you must separately commit that another project and your working copy (two separate commit operations).

Comment: That will be okay. But how can I import only that specific branch to an external repository?